# Append JSON data into custom JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am attempting to load some json data into a custom JQuery function. There is probably an easy solution to this by I am admittedly learning as I go. Please advise if I am just going about it the wrong way.

As of now I am just appending it into the body to ensure that I am actually finding the data properly. I was trying to use append() to add it into the function as well but was not getting any where.

```
$.getJSON("designs/new.json",function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("body").append(field['hex'] + " ");
        });
});
```

Essentially what I'd like to do is replace the hex data values for this colorPicker function with the hex codes from my json data above. I've been messing with it for a while and can't seem to find the right approach.

```
$.fn.colorPicker.defaults.colors = ['000', '000', 'fff', 'fff'];
```

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: `console.dir()` is awesome for dumping objects in the console: `function (result) {console.dir(result)}` (bring up the console by pressing F12 in FF and Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using alert(JSON.stringify(result)) to see if your json data is loaded properly. This code should work:

```
$.getJSON("t.json", function (result) {
  //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  $.fn.colorPicker.defaults.colors = result.colors;
});
```

where t.json has the following content:

```
{
  "colors": ['00a', '00b', 'ffa', 'ffb']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

1)  Your JSON returns an array of objects (presumably four?) that each have a "hex" property.
2)  You want to set the color picker's default colors based on these four hex properties.

So, assuming that my assumptions are correct and your array is properly ordered, you could do something like this:

```
$.getJSON("designs/new.json",function(result){
        $.fn.colorPicker.defaults.colors = $.map(result, function(i) {
            return i.hex;
        });
});
```

I've mapped the hex properties to an array and assigned it directly to the colors.  Again, this is assuming you have an array of four objects in your result object, each with a hex property.